# Why is char* p = "..." right but int* p = {1,2} wrong?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
const char *cval = "nothing";  // This is right.
int *ival = {1, 2, 3, 4};  // This is wrong.
```

Why the first is right but the second is wrong ?

Comment: With three different language tags, it's impossible to know how to answer this question.

Comment: Why is this tagged as `c` and `c++`? Tag it only for the way you are compiling it.

Comment: For c++11 both are wrong, you can only bind string literals to `const char*`

Comment: `int ival[] = {1, 2, 3, 4}; // This is right`

Comment: short version: string literals exist, and other literals don't. Brace-enclosed initializer lists are not literal values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is so because the language specification says so (independently for each respective language).

In both C and C++ string literal is a nameless *object*, an lvalue. Since it is an object, you can point to it with a pointer. At the same time `{1, 2, 3, 4}` is just a syntactic construct that does not represent an object. It is just a formal sequence of characters that form aggregate initializer syntax.

Meanwhile, in C language (since C99) there's a feature called *compound literal*, which allows one to form nameless objects of aggregate types. For example, the following initialization is valid

```
int *ival = (int []) {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

This is basically the "int array" counterpart of the first declaration. So, from C point of view, your second declaration is "wrong" simply because you used improper syntax.

Answer (score 5):

```
char *cval = "nothing";  // This is right.
```

String literals have special treatment - the compiler knows to put the text "nothing\0" in some (immutable) memory somewhere, with type `char[]`, then the array decays to a `char*` that you can copy into `cval` (for C++03 and earlier, in C++11 you should use `const char*`).  This contrasts with...

```
int *ival = {1, 2, 3, 4};  // This is wrong.
```

...where the compiler's not expected to necessarily store {1,2,3,4} in readonly memory - it just needs to either:

- for assignment to arrays - copy the values into successive array locations in the locally declared object (but when `ival` is an `int*` there's no memory allocated for the values to be put into)
- for classes with constructors accepting `initializer_list`s, create one and invoke that constructor.

Comment: And with the int pointer, the compiler gives you no way of determining the array size.

Comment: Mind you, the same applies for the string literal. You need `strlen` at runtime to find the size, if you only have a `char const*`.